# How to add Parallax Effects to List Item in android

Tags: android, listview, android-animation, parallax

I have an listview in my app, which displays list of images only. Now I want to add parallax effect for list items while scrolling the listview. I just now implemented listview only.

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell, you need to set a header to your ListView. This header will contain the image you want to apply a parallax on as well as the content that should go over (it usually is a classic ListView header but it could as well be something that looks like any element of your list).

The second main thing is to add a `ScrollListener` to your `ListView`, and create a custom ImageView (which overrides `ImageView`) that is able to receive how much your list has scrolled. In the `onScroll` callback, you can retrieve the first element of the list if it is visible, do a `getTop()` on it and send it to your custom ImageView.

You now have an ImageView that knows where it is on the screen even when your List scrolls. All you need to know is to translate the Y of your view (with either `canvas.translate()` or `view.translate()` depending on which SDK version you're working on).

I don't think it takes much more time than integrating a library and it works great!

Answer (score 0):

I generally use `ParallaxListView` by Gnod. Check the below link

https://github.com/Gnod/ParallaxListView

Comment: That's add effects for outside the listview, not for the list item. I want to add that for every list item.

Comment: I was about to comment and state this as well